# How to get rid of "Animator is not playing an AnimtorController" warning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I have a class which handles all of my animations and they work quite well at the moment. However, when I "manually trigger" them, I get the following warnings:

> Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkAnimator:FixedUpdate()

and:

> Animator is not playing an AnimatorController
>   UnityEngine.Animator:SetBool(String, Boolean) PlayerAnimation:Update()

Please note that my animations work properly in "Play Mode" and I only get these warnings when I trigger them in the editor while in "Play Mode". I've searched and tried some solutions online but none of them have worked so far. Let me know if you want me to post some of the code in my `Animation` class.

Comment: This seems to be related to a Multiplayer Setup? Does the `Animator` component on "both sides"(client & server) have an `AnimationController` referenced?